# Allow only one or two consecutives carriage return in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am stuck on a preg_replace(I guess that's what I need) synthax.

I would like to clean a string from multiples carriage return (Only allow up to 2 following carriage return, not more.)

So these strings would be left untouched :

- "Some text **\n** some text"
- "Some text **\n\n** some text **\n** some other text"

And this one would need to get change:

- "Some text **\n\n\n** some text"

into

- "Some text **\n\n** some text"

I guess there is an easy way to do that, but I am not used to regex so any help would be appreciated.

Romain.

Comment: Are they just newline's or carriage returns?

Comment: Well, I'am storing a textarea's value in database (php/mysql).
So, when the user press enter, it's stored as \n in database. I just want to prevent user to use crazy numbers of consecutives return lines, otherwise it could be annoying to display.

So, just \n I guess. The solution from Fede seems to works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex like this:

```
\n\n\n+
```

With a replacement string:

```
\n\n
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/zB4aW1/1)**

Code

```
$re = "/\\n\\n\\n+/"; 
$str = "\"Some text \n some text\"\n\n\"Some text \n\n some text \n some other text\"\n\nSome text \n\n\n some text"; 
$subst = "\n\n"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: @RomainDerie glad to help